# MySQL: Possible to write a query that is the functional equivalent to a FindListRoot?

Tags: mysql

I am not a heavy MySQL user but I can get around. I am wondering if SQL has an equivalent to a 'find list root' for a Linked list equivalent data relationship.

I have 3 columns:
`ID`, `Data`, and `ParentID`. The `ParentID` refers to another row in the same table.

The Question: Given an arbitrary entry, can you replace the functional style of keep querying until `ParentID` is NULL, with a single SELECT query?

Example Data:

```
1, x, NULL
2, y, 1
3, z, 2
```

If I start with the row: `<3, z, 2>`. It would then look up the entry: `<2, y, 1>`. Then would look up the entry: `<1, x, NULL>`.

Comment: In MySQL 8.0 you can do it with a recursive CTE.

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20181221162916/http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Comment: I think you have misphrased your question. You asked "Can you keep qerying until ParentID is NULL" and of course the answer is yes - but I think you want to ask how to get that answer *without* having to do so - usin a single query instead of the multiple SELECTs youhave identified.

Comment: This is correct Rob, Barmar shows a great example of setting the data up in a nested set model to achieve a single query by using additional left,right values   to overcome the shortcomings of needing to know the list length for X Left Joins. In a functional language, iterating until Parent = NULL is trivial as you pointed out. My data model is always a list and not a tree so was hoping for a good trick. Luckily I am in the boat of having a very short max list length, 6 deep, but is an interesting problem to solve for N depth. I edited the OP to add your clarification, thanks